# Git no such file or directory

Tags: git

I'm building an application and as always I'm using Git for version control.

Below are the inputs and outputs, hope you can help me:

```
# git status
On branch master
Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
        app/CodeBehind/Con.php

# git add app/CodeBehind/Con.php
fatal: unable to stat 'app/CodeBehind/Con.php': No such file or directory
```

To me that doesn't make any sense and I haven't found a solution yet, I read in two post that I should remove the file from Git, something like `git rm "[fileName]"` but it doesn't find a match with the file name `Con.php`.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Are you sure that you have the right path?  Can you echo this file to the command line using that path?

Comment: Have you tried this git add *

Comment: Yes I'm in the right path I have 2 more files in the same path and those didn't get me any problem. and I tried git add * and the same problem git \#add *
fatal: unable to stat 'app/CodeBehind/Con.php': No such file or directory

Comment: What operating system are you on, and which version of git are you using?

Comment: Are you perhaps using cygwin and the file is is a semi-deleted state, held in existence by a windows filehandle but cygwin tried to delete it?

Comment: @JeffPuckettII git version 2.10.1.windows.1 on Windows 10

Comment: @Mort not really, I just created it and I wrote some code, then I tried to add it to commit.

Comment: Does a `git add -A` help? Does the file get added when you do that?

Comment: Hmm, another thought. Since you mentioned that you are on Windows, have you hit the Maximum path length Limitation of [260](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/aa365247%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#maxpath) characters? How many characters doe the complete path of `Con.php` have? Can you try shortening the path if that is the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Pathname too long problem

Given that the OP has already tried removing and re-adding the file without success, it is possible that the crux of the problem is that the complete path of `Con.php` has hit the [260](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/aa365247%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#maxpath) character limit in windows. However, when I tried to reproduce this problem, the error message clearly said `fatal: unable to stat 'very/long/path/name': Filename too long` so am not certain that that is the problem.

To check if this is the problem, *switch to the directory containing `Con.php`* and execute the following:

```
pwd -W | wc -c
```

That should give you a count of the number of characters in the windows path of the current directory. If the count is *not* >=260 then this is not the problem and I would recommend moving on to `Debugging other issues` section below. However, if the count is >= 260, then proceed as follows:

```
git config --system core.longpaths true
```

and then try adding the file again.

---

See this in action below, which creates a path with >260 characters and the sets the above option to prove that it fixes the problem.

```bash
$ git add 12345
fatal: unable to stat 'This/Is/A/Very/long/pathname/with/more/than/two/hundred/and/sixty/characters/This/Is/A/Very/long/pathname/with/more/than/two/hundred/and/sixty/characters/This/Is/A/Very/long/pathname/with/more/than/two/hundred/more/dir/12345': Filename too long

$ git config --system core.longpaths true
$ git add 12345  #Notice that there is no error now
$ git status     #Shows that the file was successfully staged

On branch master

Initial commit

Changes to be committed:
  (use "git rm --cached <file>..." to unstage)

        new file:   12345
```

**Why is this configuration not the default?**

If you were wondering about that, read **[this](https://github.com/msysgit/msysgit/wiki/Git-cannot-create-a-file-or-directory-with-a-long-path#opt-in-configuration)**:

> Windows does not properly support files and directories longer than
>   260 characters. This applies to Windows Explorer, cmd.exe and many
>   other applications (including many IDEs as well as bash, perl and tcl
>   that come with Git for Windows).

and note this caveat:

> Scripted git commands may still fail with this option, so use at your
>   own risk

---

#### Debugging other issues

If too-long-a-pathname is not the problem, then try executing the following command (of course changing `git add 12345` to `git add app/CodeBehind/Con.php`) and look at the ouptput for clues (and add this to your question to assist other readers in finding out the issue) :

```bash
$ set -x; GIT_TRACE=2 GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=2 GIT_TRACE_PERFORMANCE=2 GIT_TRACE_PACK_ACCESS=2 GIT_TRACE_PACKET=2 GIT_TRACE_PACKFILE=2 GIT_TRACE_SETUP=2 GIT_TRACE_SHALLOW=2 git add 12345; set +x;

+ GIT_TRACE=2
+ GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=2
+ GIT_TRACE_PERFORMANCE=2
+ GIT_TRACE_PACK_ACCESS=2
+ GIT_TRACE_PACKET=2
+ GIT_TRACE_PACKFILE=2
+ GIT_TRACE_SETUP=2
+ GIT_TRACE_SHALLOW=2
+ git add 12345
16:06:04.269773 trace.c:333             setup: git_dir: .git
16:06:04.269773 trace.c:334             setup: git_common_dir: .git
16:06:04.269773 trace.c:335             setup: worktree: C:/Users/az/test-long-path-problems
16:06:04.269773 trace.c:336             setup: cwd: C:/Users/az/test-long-path-problems
16:06:04.269773 trace.c:337             setup: prefix: This/Is/A/Very/long/pathname/with/more/than/two/hundred/and/sixty/characters/This/Is/A/Very/long/pathname/with/more/than/two/hundred/and/sixty/characters/This/Is/A/Very/long/pathname/with/more/than/two/hundred/more/dir/
16:06:04.269773 git.c:350               trace: built-in: git 'add' '12345'
16:06:04.269773 trace.c:435             performance: 0.006209300 s: git command: 'git.exe' 'add' '12345'
+ set +x
```

Comment: The too-long-a-pathname was not the problem, I ran the set -x; GIT_TRACE=2 GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=2 GIT_TRACE_PERFORMANCE=2 GIT_TRACE_PACK_ACCESS=2 GIT_TRACE_PACKET=2 GIT_TRACE_PACKFILE=2 GIT_TRACE_SETUP=2 GIT_TRACE_SHALLOW=2 git add app/CodeBehind/Con.php; set +x;

Comment: And there was not output, but then I tried again to run >git add .   and It was successful

Answer (score 8):

OK that happened to me and it turns out that the new windows "controlled folder" protection feature is blocking git. adding git to the allowed apps list solved the problem.

Comment: Feel free to accept your own answer if it actually solves your problem.

Comment: Fixed my issue too. Thank you! This was driving me nuts.

Comment: It would be great if the author added more details on how to achieve that

Comment: its in windows control panel , search for controlled access

Answer (score 0):

check that you have the .gitconfig file it's an a.txt file.
that's was my commits were not working because I had deleted it when cleaning up my pc
.........

```
git config --global --list
```

will list these object below

```
user.name=**********
```

user.email=*********

Answer (score -1):

I faced the same issue..
go to Virus & threat protection setting and then off the controlled folder access option below.
and then try again . it will run.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Your answer is identical to [EKanadily answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56699729/2125110) above, which was posted in 2019. How are you adding value to this thread?

Comment: @DaemonPainter Is "adding git to the allowed apps list" the same thing as "off the controlled folder access option below" ???