# Git Stat: no such file or directory

Tags: git

I'm using macOS Catalina. No Matter what I try, I get a commit error.  I've already tried:

```
git rm -rf --cached <path-to-file>
```

Here is me trying to add and then commit:

```
 ➜  payments git:(eric/refactorsalfailworker) ✗ git st
On branch eric/refactorsalfailworker
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/eric/refactorsalfailworker'.

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add/rm <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

        deleted:    pkg/payments-webhooks-worker/helpers-deposit-fail.go
        deleted:    pkg/payments-webhooks-worker/helpers-deposit.go
        modified:   pkg/payments-webhooks-worker/helpers-go-routines.go
        deleted:    pkg/payments-webhooks-worker/helpers-monthly-payment.go
        deleted:    pkg/payments-webhooks-worker/helpers-mvr.go

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
➜  payments git:(eric/refactorsalfailworker) ✗ git add .
➜  payments git:(eric/refactorsalfailworker) ✗ git commit -m 'added prev boolean'
stat pkg/payments-webhooks-worker/helpers-deposit-fail.go: no such file or directory
stat pkg/payments-webhooks-worker/helpers-deposit.go: no such file or directory
stat pkg/payments-webhooks-worker/helpers-monthly-payment.go: no such file or directory
stat pkg/payments-webhooks-worker/helpers-mvr.go: no such file or directory
COMMIT FAILED
➜  payments git:(eric/refactorsalfailworker) ✗ git st
On branch eric/refactorsalfailworker
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/eric/refactorsalfailworker'.

Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

        deleted:    pkg/payments-webhooks-worker/helpers-deposit-fail.go
        deleted:    pkg/payments-webhooks-worker/helpers-deposit.go
        modified:   pkg/payments-webhooks-worker/helpers-go-routines.go
        deleted:    pkg/payments-webhooks-worker/helpers-monthly-payment.go
        deleted:    pkg/payments-webhooks-worker/helpers-mvr.go
```

The add . is definitely working, but git for some reason just isn't allowing the commit.  When I run the rm -rf --cached it says it can't find the file.  It tried it with full path and relative path.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40178828/git-no-such-file-or-directory - Mentions either to enable long path names for git or add your folder to "allowed apps" for the windows controlled folder feature.

Comment: What OS are you running ? Can you add the output of `git st` after your `git add .` ?

Comment: @LeGEC just added, using macOS Catalina

Comment: @zrrbite looks like that question is specifically about Windows, this is on macOS

Comment: This is a problem with one of your hooks, probably a `pre-commit` hook.  If you don't want to use that hook, delete it from `.git/hooks`; otherwise, include the hook and any relevant details in your question.

Comment: @bk2204 that was it, thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mention in "[Skip Git commit hooks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7230886/6309)", it is preferable to:

- try a `git commit -n -m "..."` in order to avoid any pre-commit and commit-msg hooks.
- then try and edit the culprit hook, making it more robust (in this instance, detect any deletion file and *not* operate on those files, since they are no longer in the working tree)